# Updating state of a component responsible for displaying status during data fetch

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to create a status component in my application, which will be updated during data fetch and other network related events.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
// This check is required otherwise setting state
// from here will end up in a rendering loop
if(!_.isEqual(this.props, nextProps)){
  if(nextProps.services.length != 0){
    if(nextProps.filters.length == 0){
      nextProps.setStatus('Fetching filters...');
      const { serviceId } = nextProps.params;
      const serviceIndex = nextProps
                            .services
                            .findIndex(
                                (service) => service.id == serviceId
                              );
      const serviceObj = nextProps.services[serviceIndex]; 
      nextProps.getFilters(serviceObj);
    } 
  }  
}
```

}
Here I am using componentWillReceiveProps life cycle event to load some data based on another set of data in store (due to dependency). The setStatus method is responsible for updating the store with the new status message and according to that a Status component will be updated. Here  you can see, I am checking if the  filters are empty, I am setting the status and trying to fetch the data. Now when I am setting the status it is updating the store thus firing the "render" process again. This will call the life cycle events again and as the filters are still empty it will do the data fetch request again. Currently, I have stopped this using

```
// Setting status will set the state and invoke data collection 
      // again as filters are still empty due to re-render 
      if(_.isEqual(this.props.status,nextProps.status) &&
        _.isEqual(this.props.filters,nextProps.filters)) {
        const { serviceId } = nextProps.params;
        const serviceIndex = nextProps
                              .services
                              .findIndex(
                                  (service) => service.id == serviceId
                                );
        const serviceObj = nextProps.services[serviceIndex]; 
        nextProps.getFilters(serviceObj);
      }
```

But this approach is more like a hack. Can you please suggest any better design approach for this status component? Can I maintain a controlled component?

Answer (score 0):

I'll admit that what you are specifically trying to accomplish is a bit unclear to me, but from what it seems, I should think you should be creating a Redux event to inform your component of the different steps of this process and hitting action creators in response. If you're trying to track state in some way outside of the Redux store, you'll get yourself into trouble.

Comment: I am keeping track of "status" through the redux store only, but that is what creating trouble for me. I am trying to inform users that I am trying to fetch data from the server and in order to do that I am updating the store and hitting the render process again. This next render is resending the request to the server as filter section (in the example) is still empty which is considered as a step to fetch the data to fill that up.